# Is it possible in Unity to know which objects are currently colliding from a Custom Editor Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started my internship yesterday and i had to learn custom editor scripting to help developing a Unity plug-in.

It was very simple, but now i have this task. I would like to create this functionality with **the fewest scripts as possible**, so I kind of know how to do it with other scripts, but if it exist a way to know when 2 objects collide from one only external method that could be better.

Thanks ^^

Comment: How exact do you need this? And exactly what for? By editor script you mean without entering PlayMode right? would it be enough to approximate by using e.g. [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) or one of the variants?

Comment: I'm trying with the method CollisionEnter etc... with [ExecuteInEditMode]. And yeah i need it rly precise. The exact purpose of it hasn't been precised to me, but what i need is to Highlight colliding objects when i press a button (In Edit Mode).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using unity physics, you can use

```
OnCollisionEnter(), OnCollisionStay(), OnTriggerEnter...
```

Depending on your situation. Otherwise if you are using custom scripts for collision, check if there are functions that return the GameObject of collision.

Comment: What i want to do is Coloring the objects that collides in Edit Mode